# Issue in Eclipse at application creation

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-fragments

When we create an android application in eclipse  by default its starts with activity (i.e) the MainActivity class extends the activity class
But when I create an android application by defaults it extends the ActionBarActivity in layout fragement_main.xml is created 
Here I dont want to extend the ActionBarActivity class 
How to avoid this Here I attached the image
[image: Here I attached the image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: Same happened with me when updated SDK to 4.4, I think it is a part of updated ADT.

Comment: @Virag Same thing happend to me a hour ago.Yesterday me to had updated the ADT.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why eclipse automatically adds appcompat v7 library support whenever i create a new project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261288/why-eclipse-automatically-adds-appcompat-v7-library-support-whenever-i-create-a)

Comment: Unfortunately this is now the default behaviour see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67513. You will have to create a project from the command line outside Eclipse or heavily edit what you now have.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an `"issue"`.I once had the same situation but in Android Studio.Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876874/what-is-the-difference-between-acitvity-main-xml-and-fragment-main-xml-files-in) question.Should help you understand the situation better.You can work on the `fragment_main.xml` just like you would on the `activity_main.xml`

Answer (score 0):

If you set your minimum required `SDK` below 11 it will create the application like this because in API level below 11 there is no `ActionBar`. The default value is 8. You should set it 14 and then you can change it in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: just clean and build it will be again automatically made and also look in mainfeast.xml and in res Is there any error at there