# Android NullPointerException when findViewById

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

when i run my app i get this error in the log-cat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.myfirstapp.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
... 11 more
```

Here's line 52:

```
String message = editTextInput.getText().toString();
```

So far i've worked out that the NPE must be when I define the EditText (or any view for that matter):

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_text);
```

However though, I don't get an NPE when I define a EditText without: `findViewById()` like this View:

```
TextView desc = new TextView(this);
```

Here is the entire `onCreate()` method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_text);
    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, testActivity.class);
    final TextView desc = new TextView(this);
    final TextView title = new TextView(this);

    String message = editText.getText().toString();

    submit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);}});

    desc.setTextSize(20);
    desc.setText(message);
    desc.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP);
    desc.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    desc.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

    title.setTextSize(10);
    title.setText(R.string.title_activity_dictionary);
    title.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP);
    title.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    title.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

    layout.addView(desc);
    layout.addView(title);
}
```

What I dont get is why is there a NPE when I clearly define the View?

Comment: Copy the whole contents in `fragment_main.xml` to `activity_main.xml` and try..

Comment: Thankyou soooo much, finally cracked it! Thanks dude. However what's the point of having a fragment_main then? @Lal

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876874/what-is-the-difference-between-acitvity-main-xml-and-fragment-main-xml-files-in) for that @user3625982

Comment: I've added that as my answer..Kindly mark it as accepted..Please..

Comment: Oops sorry i'm new to this forums :) ill try work it out now @Lal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because findViewById() searches in the activity_main layout, while the button is located in the fragment's layout fragment_main.

Move that piece of code in the onCreateView() method of the fragment:

```
//...

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
Button buttonClick = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onButtonClick((Button) view);
    }
});
```

Notice that now you access it through rootView view:

```
Button buttonClick = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

otherwise you would get again NullPointerException.

Comment: Also is it possible to add the code above into the OnCreate(); instead of OnCreateView(); ?

Comment: That i'm not sure @user3625982

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are passing the correct id in findviewbyid method which is available in your layout..

Otherwise. Just clean and build the project.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
String message = editTextInput.getText().toString();
```

To

```
String message = editText.getText().toString();
```